# SQL-how can i product/ multiply across partitions with window functions

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, dbt

The [input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ynxl1.jpg) I have is composed of the following columns: `time`, `UseID`, and `value`. I want to get the `plt` column as the product of successive numbers.

I know about the existence of the `SUM` window function to apply sum over rows, but how to handle the product?

| time | UseID | value | plt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| t1 | 116C123 | a | a |
| t2 | 116C123 | b | a*b |
| t3 | 116C123 | c | a*b*c |
| t4 | 116C123 | d | a*b*c*d |
| t2 | 116C111 | a1 | a1 |
| t3 | 116C111 | b1 | a1*b1 |
| t4 | 116C111 | c1 | a1*b1*c1 |

**Note**: the output should be in the domain of real numbers.

Comment: Is the value a string or it is some real number? I mean what output you expect: a formula or a calculated value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use logarithms for this!

```
log(x) + log(y) = log(x*y) ==> x*y = exp(log(x) + log(y))
```

so your query becomes:

```sql
select
    time,
    UseID,
    value,
    exp(
        sum(ln(value)) over (
            partition by UseID
            order by time asc
            rows between unbounded preceding and current row
        )
    ) as plt
from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Attention: This solution will work on a Postgres DB, not on a Redshift DB. I created this because first Postgres was tagged in the question as DB type. If I should remove the answer, please let me know.

Assuming the last line of your sample data is incorrect (should be useid 116C111    instead of 116C123), you could do something like this to do a multiplication:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE MULTIPLICATE(int8) (SFUNC = int8mul, STYPE = int8);
```

and then use this in your query:

```
SELECT
time,
useid,
value,
MULTIPLICATE(value) OVER (PARTITION BY useid ORDER BY useid, value) AS plt
FROM input 
GROUP BY useid, value, time
ORDER BY useid, value, time;
```

Please see the working example here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=2d5a1bb726f1aedbe67192130e41e80a)

If your sample data really is correct, you should please describe the logic behind it.

Comment: thank you. the sample data is incorrect. I had edited it.

Comment: Does this or at least a similar solution work on your DB or are there too many differences between Postgres DB and your DB?

Comment: This solution not work in my DB. create aggregate can not run in redshift